# Resolvent identity, densely defined operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

> Let $L:D \rightarrow H$ be a densely defined, closed, and symmetric operator. Then we know we may define bounded inverse $R(z): im (L-z) \rightarrow D$, where $im(L-z)$ is closed subset of $H$.

Prove:

> If $z,w$ are distinct, strictly complex numbers, with $R(z)$ and $R(w)$ are defined everywhere, then prove that 
>   $$ (z-w)R(z)R(w)= R(z)-R(w)$$

---

Reference: [Tao's blog, Exercise 8(i)](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/#more-5573) I do not even understand the given hint (what does $H$ mean in this case?)

Comment: $H$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: I meant the $H$ in the given hint of the exercise.  (and yes, $H$ is a hilbert space)

Comment: Typo, should be $L$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got this.

$$\begin{align} R_z - R_w &= R_z(L-w)R_w - R_z(L-z)R_w \\ &= R_zLR_w-R_zLR_w +R_z(z-w)R_w\\
&= (z-w)R_zR_w  \end{align} $$